# List Item text Overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to fix the overlapping of the text in the the `li` when zooming in but i am unable to find a solution here is the link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5Q8y/). 
if anyone is able to help me i will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've updated:

- moved *hyperlinks* inside *listItems*
- removed float:right inside cells
- added min-width to first cell of every column
- removed width attribute to seconds cells

**CSS**

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#main_forums li:hover {
  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#main_forums .main_forum_container li {
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 900px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#main_forums {
}

.sub_description {
 min-width:300px;
}

#main_forums .main_forum {
  background: #880000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #800;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main_forum_header {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main_forum_container {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #800;
  border: 4px solid #800;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="main_forums">
    <div class="main_forum">
      <div class="main_forum_header">
        <img src="images/programming.png" height="70" width="70">
        <span class="main_forum_title">Programming</span>
      </div>
      <div class="main_forum_container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?p=forums&amp;forum_id=2&amp;sub_id=1">
              <img src="images/php.png" height="60" width="60">
              <table border="1">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description" >
                      <span>PHP - Web Programming</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin-right: 0px;">Posts: 12011</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description" style="font-size: 12px;" >PHP web applications.</td>
                    <td>Views: 12012311</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?p=forums&amp;forum_id=2&amp;sub_id=2">
              <img src="images/python.png" height="60" width="60" />
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description" >
                      <span>Python - Application Programming</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin-right: 0px;">Posts: 12011</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description" style="font-size: 12px;" >Python Application programming</td>
                    <td>Views: 12012311</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_forum">
      <div class="main_forum_header">
        <img src="images/web_developing.png" height="70" width="70" />
        <span class="main_forum_title">Web Developing</span>
      </div>
      <div class="main_forum_container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?p=forums&amp;forum_id=1&amp;sub_id=4">
              <img src="images/css.png" height="60" width="60" />
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description">
                      <span>CSS</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin-right: 0px;">Posts: 12011
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description" style="font-size: 12px;" >Cascading Style Sheets</td>
                    <td>Views: 12012311</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?p=forums&amp;forum_id=1&amp;sub_id=3">
              <img src="images/html.png" height="60" width="60" />
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description">
                      <span>HTML</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin-right: 0px;">Posts: 12011</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sub_description" style="font-size: 12px;" >HyperText Markup Language</td>
                    <td>Views: 12012311</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I get the Same results the text is overlaping.

Comment: Can't see any difference.

Comment: @user2444411 removed useless float:right in cells, seems work, what browser are you using?

Comment: I am currently have tested on firefox and on Chrome i seem to be having the same error: http://oi58.tinypic.com/21nkyaa.jpg

Comment: @user2444411 found, it was the 800 width to your cells, try now, it will appeen in my broswer when resize the window

Comment: Thank yeah that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for the tables? The first thing I would do is remove the tables. In fact none of your HTML is semantic. You have  tables inside of li tags and li tags surrounded by hyperlinks.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="?p=forums&amp;forum_id=2&amp;sub_id=1">
        <img src="images/php.png" height="60" width="60">
        <span>PHP - Web Programming</span>
        Posts: 12011
        PHP web applications.   
        Views: 12012311
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="?p=forums&amp;forum_id=2&amp;sub_id=2">
        <img src="images/python.png" height="60" width="60">
        <span>Python - Application Programming</span>
        Posts: 12011
        Python Application programming      
        Views: 12012311
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLy92/
See how that already cleans things up? These are all in-line elements so they line up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash() in that      `<a href="?p=forums&amp;forum_id=1&amp;sub_id=4">\`

Comment: check the code properly slash is there thats why overlapping